# cannot import name 'ConfusionMatrixDisplay' from 'sklearn.metrics'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I receive an error message:

```
cannot import name 'ConfusionMatrixDisplay' from 'sklearn.metrics'".
```

when I run the following import code:

```
from sklearn.metrics import ConfusionMatrixDisplay
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Just to make sure: Have you installed sklearn in your python environment? For example via pip install or conda install?

Comment: I am using your code and the error I get is different and is related to the positional argument. You probably need to re-installed the `sklearn`.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely your version of sklearn is outdated -
`sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay` was added in `sklearn>=1.0.0`.

[Source (docs)](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay.html)

You can check your sklearn version with:

`python3 -m pip show scikit-learn`