# ImportError: cannot import name 'ConfusionMatrixDisplay' from 'sklearn.metrics'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

How I can resolve the error from the import code below?

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix, ConfusionMatrixDisplay
```

Error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'ConfusionMatrixDisplay' from 'sklearn.metrics' (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\__init__.py)
```

Comment: Found similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71141703/cannot-import-name-confusionmatrixdisplay-from-sklearn-metrics

Comment: Update your sklearn.